# How can I remove the red "Google Groups will no longer be supporting the Welcome Message feature" from my Google group?

Tags: google-groups

I want to remove the red message which says

> Google Groups will no longer be
>   supporting the Welcome Message
>   feature. Starting 13 January, you
>   won't be able to edit your welcome
>   messages, but you will still be able
>   to view and download the existing
>   content. See this announcement for
>   more information and other options for
>   storing your content. [ Download
>   Welcome Message Content ]

I tried making the message empty and I hoped that this red message would go away after 13 January, but it is still there and I find it ugly.

How can I remove it?

Answer (score 1):

According to [this article](http://groups.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1046705), Google are switching this feature off during Feb 2011 so maybe you have to wait until they do this.

Alternatively, I don't know if you have done this or are able to do this, but you could switch your Group to the new style which is discussed in detail in [this article.](http://www.groups.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=1047449)